# Why is the vote/flag gap not calculated

Tags: discussion, comments

I've noticed something that annoys my OCD every now and then.

When you are the first one to comment on a question, your comment appears **without the space for upvotes / flags :**

> [image]

When you refresh the page, it gets fixed :

> [image]

But if you are not the first one to comment, this gap is already calculated without the need to refresh the page.

I don't think this is a bug but I would like someone to explain how it works and why it does that.

Comment: Actually, I’ve noticed even stranger behaviour! No gap. Refresh: gap. Refresh an hour later (I don’t know exactly how long it takes or if this still happens – hence this comment) and it’s back to no gap. Whaa?

Comment: @minitech Simply bugging me a little. Just tickling my ocd.

Comment: (… and it only works if mine are the only comments. To the formatting sandbox I go.)