# New badge for getting 10 upvotes out of 100 views

Tags: feature-request, badge-request

A badge for questions which get upvotes from high ratio of viewers would be good I think. It should kick in at something like... 100 views, and if question has enough upvotes (or total votes with positive total?) at that point, badge should be awarded.

10 upvotes at 100 views would perhaps be a bit tough (looking at numbers in [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=week)), but then again this does not have to be an easy badge, it could be silver or even gold depending on the stats.

*Redacted proposed badge name as courtesy to those who think it is bad taste.*

**The rationale**: If someone writes so good a question, that 10th of people looking at it think it is worth a upvote, it must be a good question. And this would not be awarded simply by virtue of having many views on an attractive question, where many views equal many upvotes, simple as that. This would be, many upvotes for (relatively) few views, which makes it different from current upvote badges.

**Response to a sockpuppet/friend comment**: 10 upvotes would indeed be achievable by friends or sockpuppets. So make it like 20 upvotes for 200 views, or more. I don't know how good the sockpuppet detection algorithms are, but getting 20 sockpuppet upvotes within 200 first views would hopefully be detected. Also, if "easy badge" is argument against this badge, then it would be argument against many other badges too. Is this any worse? The color should match the difficulty anyway.

**Variation**

Give three badges like this *instead* of current "N votes" badges, if votes happened with few enough views. Or the other way around, instead of "N views" badges, if there are enough votes when that amount of views was reached. So one question would not get more badges like this, but it could get different, more special and rare badges. Because certainly getting the votes with only few views is special compared to just getting the votes over time.

Comment: Can you please explain what good behavior this would promote?

Comment: In addition to what @Oded mentioned, can you explain how that would be a better incentive than the existing badges or what gap this badge would cover?

Comment: One could just get 10 friends (or sockpuppets) to vote up the question, even if it's a bad one, giving you an easy gold badge.  Doesn't seem fair to me.

Comment: That helps. Still haven't decided if I like it or not.

Comment: @Jamal many badges can be gamed. I would not hold that against this particular proposal.

Comment: We already give badges (and reputation!) for good questions - why is an additional badge needed?

Comment: @Bart: That's true.

Comment: `Decimator`?  -1, bad pun.

Comment: @Oded This awards a different aspect than other badges, namely high *ratio* of viewers liking the question. I don't think this brings *much* new to the table, just a small aspect, if that's what you mean, but how many of the mass of badges really do?

Comment: @hyde The fact that there are other badges that don't really help doesn't justify adding more badges that also don't help.  At most, it's a justification for removing some of those other badges.

Comment: @Servy Removing some of the current badges for being trivial, I kinda agree and I would not be against that really...

Comment: @KevinPanko I suppose the suggested name may have been a bit insensitive, this being global site and all, so removed from view.

Comment: @hyde Just kidding about the -1.  Actually I just think we have enough badges, so I will not +1 this either.

Comment: @hyde I didn't personally think the name was insensitive(unless we have ancient Romans in the audience), but it didn't fit. Decimation basically means "killing 10% of the population". It's an *indisputably* negative thing, and I can't see how it applies to this badge proposal, except "random word having something to do with 10%".

Comment: @GenericHolidayName In my totally subjective view, a question "killing" 10th of the views and leaving them behind as votes fits as well as anything. But a badge named after killing people is still a bit... well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On a [certain other knowledge sharing network](http://www.quora.com/), it has been observed that posts with a conversion rate of 10% of views to votes, have a very high chance of going viral. On the Stack Exchange network, since sites are far more specific, it may be the case that the ratio would be higher. It is hard to say for sure without looking at SEDE data.

So, a 10% to 20% conversion ratio would actually be a decent *value* on which to set such a badge, *if it were to be implemented.*

Coming to the topic of whether this is needed or not, my opinion is on the side of **not**.

What would this *encourage*? Writing questions that are likely to accrue a large number of votes. Even for specialized audiences, something which many will understand and find worth voting for will likely be something non-complex and easy to grasp. Hence, the only content that this would actually promote would be easy, popular content which while great for generating traffic to a site, will not usually, improve site quality in any way. There are other badges (as well as the significant rep bump) that already cover this aspect of the Q&A side, and adding another will be detrimental in the long run.

Comment: I guess the question to ask is, would this encourage writing questions, which would be easy to find by future visitors. Wild speculation: the search engines are getting pretty good with heuristics I think, and might (if not now, then in future) also have easy time matching against such questions by their content.

Comment: @hyde Not really. Users coming in via search engines form 90% of the traffic and are largely anonymous on SO which means that they cant vote. Content going viral, atleast in the initial stage, is almost always dependent on the existing community of users, and specifically on the power users.

Comment: I think we are looking at this from different viewpoints. A question going viral would probably not help with getting this badge... More votes sure, but also more views, not necessarily more votes per view, perhaps even the opposite.

Answer (score 5):

This badge would be **futile**.
I don't see what it could add to the Popular / Good / Famous Question badges.

It would simply be another badge that you would get for asking a question that has 10 upvotes and would probably result in getting your new badge plus the already existing badge at the same time because a lot of very good questions get upvoted quickly.

Also.
Decimator.. Really?

Comment: "asking a question that has 10 upvotes": not just that, also *"and only 100 views"*. Which is actually very tough (just try to find a question which would get this). But, added variation to award these badges *instead* of the current ones. Also got rid of the badge name suggestion...

Comment: It not really possible to find it because the views don't cap at 100 so we don't know when the 100 was reached. But trust me it's not that hard to get..Close enough ? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208900/show-negative-reputation

Comment: I'm almost there guys : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208259/why-is-the-vote-flag-gap-not-calculated

Comment: Some other exemples and this.. only in my profile : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188918/complete-mobile-version-especially-the-help-center

Comment: Those are at meta... Different site profile and stats, very few anon views. I was talking about SO views. Meta would need different limit values.

Answer (score 2):

If a question gets 10 upvotes with less than 100 views, it already gives:

- Nice Question
- 100 Reputation

If the question is really *that* good, it's almost a given that it will eventually earn (at least):

- Good Question
- Popular Question
- A Pile More Rep™

How much should we reward a single question? I'd rather see something that rewards *consistent* contribution rather than overly rewarding a one-shot "winner".

Comment: The difference is, "eventually". Apparently most do not think it's an important difference, but this proposal is not a "you get it eventually" kind of badge, because a question reaching the limit views with too few votes, and the chance for the badge is over for that question.

Comment: That's probably because SE is an "eventually" kind of site. The focus is supposed to be on the *future* usefulness of the question/answer to visitors, not *just* the OP's immediate need.

Comment: My main point is that any question that would earn this new badge would also be rewarded (plenty) in other ways.

Comment: "Eventually kind of site", from point of view of future visitors sure, but the one asking a question expects answer sooner than "eventually". And site is not *only* for future visitors, it is also for those needing an answer to their own immediate problem (otherwise there would be nothing to visit in future).

Comment: As it stands, the asker gets 1) a bunch of rep, 2) at least one medal, and 3) most likely an answer. That's all in the **short term** already. I still haven't seen you explain why that isn't enough.

Comment: Added a variation to the suggestion, to give new badges *instead* of the badges you list.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing on [the lines of AnonJr](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210229/new-badge-for-geting-10-upvotes-out-of-100-views#comment673964_210229), what actual purpose would such a badge serve?

We already have badges for questions based on the number of views -

1. Popular (bronze)
2. Notable (silver)
3. Famous (gold)

In addition to that, we have badges for questions based on the number of upvotes -

1. Nice (bronze)
2. Good (silver)
3. Great (gold)

The views-based badges are for their actual relevance & number of times people have encountered the same problem & the question matched the appropriate problem details.

As for the upvotes-based badges, they genuinely guarantee that the question being asked in an incredible knowledge source for many others & the answers to these *great* questions are truly incredible at times.

Don't think any additional badges provide decent incentive for the users & might instead promote cheating to a certain extent.

Comment: " they genuinely guarantee that the question being asked in an incredible knowledge source for many others ". They most certainly do not guarantee that. The one question I've gotten gold badge on, I myself would put at the bottom 10% of all the questions I've asked.

Comment: Agreed, but the question was looked up by so many people or voted upon by many others for a reason! It was helpful!

Comment: Added a variation to the suggestion, to give new badges *instead* of the badges you list.

Answer (score 0):

I'm against this.

1) You can't vote up until you have 15 reputation and are logged in to the site.

2) One of the philosophies of the Stack Exchange sites is to provide a knowledge base for posterity and therefore many anonymous folk will view answers on the site who are unable to vote up.

I therefore submit that the ratio of upvotes to visits is a poor estimator of answer quality. **You could also lose and gain the badge frequently as the ratio changes over time.**

There are already badges in place for viewing frequency and upvoting numbers: it's pointless to add another set.

[Edit: Removed the badge name to match the question edit]

Comment: I did not mean the badge would go away, it would be a one-time event when it gets awarded (I don't know how other badges behave in this respect). The suggested name referred to taking 10th of viewers, but I agree it was overly bad taste for a global site with people with all kinds of backgrounds, so edited it out.

Comment: I believe no badges are ever taken back.  If you get a "Student" badge, and then the question gets deleted, the reputation goes away but you keep that badge anyway.